# Is output of Extension Method IEnumerable.Average() wrong for some values?

Tags: c#, linq, double

I have a follows code that i have run on LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    List<VariableData> outputVariableData = 
    new List<VariableData>();

    for(int i = 1 ; i< 100; i ++)
    {
    outputVariableData.Add(new VariableData
        { 
        Id = i,
        VariableValue = .33     
        });
    }

    double result = outputVariableData.Average(dd=> dd.VariableValue);
    double add = outputVariableData.Sum(dd=> dd.VariableValue)/99;
    add.Dump();
    result.Dump();
}

public class VariableData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public double VariableValue{ get; set; }
    }
```

It results

```
0.329999999999999
0.329999999999999
```

When i check the average of same numbers in the excel sheet with formula =AVERAGE(A1:A101) and it return .33 as it is.

Actually i am drawing chart with this data  and average value is showin on the chart, which making the chart drawing so absert and chart is not able to manage such type of value.

I am little confused about the output of these both, i suppose excel automatic round the value. so i have simple and little silly question that is output of my extension method is correct??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, excel gives you a nice rounded version.  For displaying of numbers this may be a very useful read:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

There is also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377 available.

What's the relevance of Standard Numeric Format Strings You Literally Ask?

Easy - the problem isn't that the numbers *wrong* - it's perfectly fine given the inaccuracies of floating point numbers.  However displaying these numbers can be an issue - it's not what we expect nor is it useful.  However, if we spend a few seconds defining how we want our numbers presented...

```
void Main()
{
    List<VariableData> outputVariableData = 
    new List<VariableData>();

    for(int i = 1 ; i< 100; i ++)
    {
    outputVariableData.Add(new VariableData
        { 
        Id = i,
        VariableValue = .33     
        });
    }

    double result = outputVariableData.Average(dd=> dd.VariableValue);
    double add = outputVariableData.Sum(dd=> dd.VariableValue)/99;
    add.Dump();
    add.ToString("P0").Dump();
    add.ToString("N2").Dump();
    result.Dump();
    result.ToString("P0").Dump();
    result.ToString("N2").Dump();
}

public class VariableData
{
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public double VariableValue{ get; set; }
}
```

Suddenly we get the output we want:

```
0.329999999999999
33 %
0.33

0.329999999999999
33 %
0.33
```

The problem now isn't trying to massage the numbers to perfection, or using unusual datatype - but spending a few minutes figuring out what options are available and making use of them!  It's easy to do and very useful in the long run :)

Of course, this should only be used for *displaying* data - if you need to round data for computational reasons then I suggest looking into Math.Round etc.

Hope this answers your Q.

Supplemental:

This is another option that works in a very similar vein:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx  It explains how to do things like:

```
void Main()
{
    0.31929.ToString("0.##%").Dump();
    0.ToString("0.##%").Dump();
    1.ToString("0.##%").Dump();
}
```

Which results in:

```
31.93%
0%
100%
```

Comment: can you explain what is the relation of `Standard Numeric Format Strings` to my question.

Comment: +1 well you explained it nice and placed nice links, but i am not looking for standard formats etc. my question was simply regarding the output that whether it is correct or wrong. if better someone give me the mathematical reason in C#. i have figureout this..  thanks for you efforts..

Comment: Glad I helped.  I focused on the displaying of data because from your description that sounded like the actual problem '...average value is showin on the chart, which making the chart drawing so absert...'.  As noted floating point math gives inaccuracies, just like 10/3 is inaccurate in decimal - there's plenty of resources on the web to explain this.  Hopefully though my answer lets you solve the problem - simply by rounding the answer appropriately :)

Answer (score 2):

The computer stores floating point numbers in binary format and there is no exact representation of 0.33

```
Decimal Binary
2       10
0.5     0.1
0.25    0.01
0.33    0.01010100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111000...
```

http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly how computer can present computations from Math point the numbers 0.33 and 0.32(9) are equal, Excel perhaps has own rounding

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/999999.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Floating points will give you rounding differences.  It happens.

If you want the numbers to be exact, try using decimal instead of double for VariableValue.  
This gives 0.33 for both **add** and **result**.

Comment: `decimal` isn't a perfect representation of numbers either.  You still need to deal with floating point errors, it's just that different types of numbers will have floating point errors with a decimal than with a double, and they tend to be numbers that more non-computer scientists would expect to have rounding errors so it's less confusing.  That doesn't mean you should always use decimals in every case, or that they will always solve your floating point rounding issues.

Comment: @Servy - The `decimal` data type will always represent a base 10 number perfectly. However, the result of a mathematical operation won't neccessarly be represented accuratly. Example 10/3

Comment: *"The decimal data type will always represent a base 10 number perfectly"*  It will represent a base 10 number perfectly *up to a fixed number of significant digits*.  It still has fixed precision.  The OP's code is quite vague as to what the numbers actually represent, beyond the one hard coded example.  We don't know how large they are, what kinds of numbers they will be (in the general case) or what the entire set of operations he will be performing on them are.